# touchstart not working in jquery. how to make it work in this code?

Tags: jquery

I have 'face in hole' type of application.

There are two divs with IDs 'frame' and 'face'.

'face' is behind 'frame'.

'face' fits in a hole in the 'frame'.

frame is fixed and never moves or interacts with the user.

face should move and adjust in the hole.

when we drag on the frame, face should move.

So, all events happening to the frame should happen to face.

I have this code :

```
$('#frame').mousedown(function(ev) {
    $('#face').trigger(ev);
});
```

it works fine on my laptop.

However, to make it work for touchscreens, I need it to work something like this :

```
$('#frame').touchstart(function(ev) {
    $('#face').trigger(ev);
});
```

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an in-built `.touchstart()` method in jQuery Core.

So you'll have to manually bind to that event:

```
$('#frame').on('touchstart',function(ev) {
    $('#face').trigger(ev);
}); // this might work for you
```

Comment: @Arnold glad to have helped you! You can upvote it too, if you found it helpful `;)`

Comment: The code worked for touchstart, but I also need touchmove, touchend etc. So, is there a way to pass all events to face from frame without mentioning touchstart, touchmove, touchend etc...?